# sync via p4java api

Tags: perforce, p4java

What fields should be set in the FileSpec object passed into IClient.sync in the perforce java API?

I've set:

1. The pathname passed to the constructor to the abs path/... of the local workspace
2. setClient(myIClient)
3. the action to FileAction.SYNC

No exception is thrown, but one IFileSpec comes back in the result, and it complains that the client 'unknownclient' is (not surprisingly) unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to call:

```
    IClient client = server.getClient(clientName);
    server.setCurrentClient(client);
```